# Export a table in CSV format from umbraco back-end

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, umbraco

I have got a table [newsletter] in the db, which saves the email address, What I want is to have button or a section on the umbraco back-end, where I can export the whole list of email addresses in the newsletter table in CSV format.

Can anyone provide any assistance or any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: did you ever complete this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the umbraco back end by adding a custom section. Here's a good tutorial about how to add a custom section to Umbraco...
http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/3/how-to-create-a-custom-section-in-umbraco-4

You'll need to have a web form that you can add to the custom tree in your custom section of Umbraco. This can be done by creating a new project in visual studio. Add a web form with your button on there which contains the code to do all the exporting to csv obtaining the data from your table. Then build your project and add your dll to the 'bin' folder on Umbraco.